# Restreaming mpd to m3u8 loads CPU, any solution?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, http-streaming, mpd

i restream channels from mpd to m3u8 but it loads cpu very much. Is any soliton to restream mpd streams easily?

This is code:

```
[program:channel]
autorestart=true
command=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -re -hide_banner -headers 'Referer: https://example.com/' -i https://stream.webm.mpd -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename '/etc/nginx/hls/channel/file%%03d.ts' /etc/nginx/hls/channel/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: Do you actually need to transcode?  Can you use `-vcodec copy`?  Also, have you looked into using the same media files for both DASH and HLS from the original encoding source?

Comment: No i need not transcode, i just need to reduce cpu load. Also should i add "-vcodec copy" in this code? Third question i did not understand.

Comment: I add ed "-vcodec copy" in the code and the streaming is frozen.